# PHP PDO SQL MultiThreading Possible?

Tags: php, multithreading

I send a FULL flat (EDI) file to OXFORD everyday.  I would query my database, get the array of results, and use the data array to make a csv file out of it

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM master_table";
$sth = $apex->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //this is where I would get my fatal error due to out of memory
$csv = new csv();
$csv->makeCsv($result);
```

The $result would contain an array of millions of records which I then make into a csv.

The main problem I'm having here is a lack of memory and time.  However if I "break up" the sql query like this:

```
$years = [2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011]; //etc

foreach ($years as year) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM master_table WHERE year = $year";
    $sth = $apex->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();

    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $csv = new csv();
    $csv->makeCsv($result);
    unset($result);
}
```

This works but it takes a extremely long time due to php not being unable to execute the foreach loop simultaneously.  Is there an option in PDO where I can execute multithreaded queries?

Comment: a) Your comment suggests that it's not a "memory leak" but a "memory constraint". Have you tried _not_ using fetchAll() but transfering the result step by step from the database server into the php process? b) Actually, what is your database server exactly?

Comment: @volkerK fixed.  It is pervasive SQL.

Comment: `while(fetch...) { build csv row}`. that's all you need. don't try to cache the ENTIRE result set in ram, then build csv out of it. you'll be sucking a TON of ram holding all that data, for no good reason. instead of doing it all in ram, stream the results.

Comment: you guys are right i should be inserting the row one by one

Comment: And it _might_ be as simple as `$sth->execute(); $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
foreach( $sth as $row ) {
 fputcsv($fOut, $row);
}` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Even if you could select the data faster from multiple threads (which you can't most probably), you couldn't write the CSV any faster whatever ... threading doesn't make sense here.

The best solution is to `SELECT INTO OUTFILE`, bypassing PHP in the creation of the CSV altogether.